# convert dataframe to venn diagram table

Tags: r, dataframe, data-visualization, venn-diagram

So, I writting a function that takes **dataframe** and **unique number <1, 5>**
let say we want a unique number to be 3 in this case

```
   how_much = 100
   A <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5) 
   B <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)    
   VennData <- data.frame(A, B)
```

and then return a described table as below:

```
count    A      B
 24     TRUE   TRUE
 20     TRUE   FALSE
 13     FALSE  TRUE
 43     FALSE  FALSE
```

when we can see that we have 24 observations where both A and B is equal to 3, 
20 observations have A equal to 3 and B non equal to 3,
13 observations have A not equal to 3 and B equal to 3 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `set.seed(43)`

```
library(dplyr)
VennData %>%
    mutate(A = (A == 3),
           B = (B == 3)) %>%
    count(A, B)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  A     B         n
#  <lgl> <lgl> <int>
#1 FALSE FALSE    64
#2 FALSE TRUE     20
#3 TRUE  FALSE    13
#4 TRUE  TRUE      3
```

In base R,

```
aggregate(Count ~ ., transform(VennData, A = A == 3, B = B == 3, Count = 1), sum)
#      A     B Count
#1 FALSE FALSE    64
#2  TRUE FALSE    13
#3 FALSE  TRUE    20
#4  TRUE  TRUE     3
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(43)
setDT(VennData)[, .N, .(A = A == 3, B = B == 3)]
#     A     B  N
#1: FALSE FALSE 64
#2: FALSE  TRUE 20
#3:  TRUE  TRUE  3
#4:  TRUE FALSE 13
```